# el token enviado no es valido, spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

tengo este problema, me da error 403 en insomnia y en mi terminal me aparece que el token no es valido, estoy usando spring security 3, es un curso que estoy tomando y no se que pasa, trato de logear para que me de un token y poderlo usar, puse el securityfilterchain en permitir todos para que se pueda logiar pero me sale error 403 forbiden en insomnia y en el id me sale el token no es valido eso lo puse en la clase securityFilter para tratar el error de un token vasio o nullo pero el post login no deberia darme ese error

```
package med.voll.api.infra.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations  {



   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       return http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
               .and().authorizeHttpRequests()
               .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and().build();
   }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
package med.voll.api.infra.security;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenService tokenService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // obtener el token del header
        var token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (token == null || token.equals("") ) {
            throw new RuntimeException("El token enviado no es valido");
        }
        token = token.replace("Bearer","");
        System.out.println(token);
        System.out.println(tokenService.getSubject(token));

        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

```
package med.voll.api.infra.security;


import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTCreationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTVerificationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import med.voll.api.domain.usuarios.Usuario;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

@Service
public class TokenService {

    @Value("${api.security.secret}")
    private String apiSecret;

    public String generarToken(Usuario usuario){
        try {
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(apiSecret);
           return JWT.create()
                    .withIssuer("voll med")
                    .withSubject(usuario.getLogin())
                   .withClaim("id", usuario.getId())
                   .withExpiresAt(generarFechaExpiracion())
                    .sign(algorithm);
        } catch (JWTCreationException exception){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    public String getSubject(String token) {
        DecodedJWT verifier = null;
        try {
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(apiSecret);
            verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                    .withIssuer("voll med")
                    .build()
                    .verify(token);
            if (verifier != null && verifier.getSubject() != null) {
                return verifier.getSubject();
            }else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Verifier invalido");
            }
        } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.toString());
            throw  new RuntimeException("Error de verificacion JWT");
        }



    }

    private Instant generarFechaExpiracion(){
        return LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(2).toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
    }
}
```

ruta en insominia http://localhost:8080/login
{
"login": "irving.valencia",
"clave": "123456"
}

se supone que tendria que lograr logearme para poder sacar un token ya quie en securityFilterChain puse .permitAll pero me sale el token enviado no es valido